# WiFi only works when specific phone is present

Tags: wireless-networking

At my mother-in-law (MIL) , my wife's and MIL's phones and my laptop have problems connecting to the secondary access point (TP-link 841 with OpenWrt) when my phone is *not* connected to the WiFi. I do not have any problems on the phone.

The secondary access point is in the center of the house, it is connected with UTP cable to the main router. The main router is provided by the ISP, and sits in one corner of the house, where the ISP installed it.

If my phone is not there or not connected to the wifi, the secondary wifi basically does not work. It has the same SSID encryption and password as the main wifi, but different channel.
What could cause this? How can I troubleshoot and end this problem?

Comment: Turn your phone all the off, leave it off, and reset completely the secondary access point. That should work.

Comment: I'd add to John's comment: Turn everything off, router, etc.  Wait 60 seconds to allow capacitors to discharge.  Then power up router, secondary access point, and everything else.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I upgraded openwrt, reset the AP, gave it new SSID, now the other phones cannot connect with or without my phone